# What does "cough gas nightmare" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Today I watched a video clip of ABC news [Britney Spears father is no longer part of her conservatorship](https://youtu.be/J2-59rIZ3xs?t=47). At about the 47th second, the spokesman (or maybe he is the attorney) says the following:

> Britney Spears has been faced with a decade-long nightmare, a **cough gas nightmare**, orchestrated by <s>his</s> her father and others.

I don't understand the metaphor of "cough gas" here. I know the point is that what she has experienced is a nightmare. But what information does "cough gas" add to it or what feeling does "cough gas" suggest?

I search "cough gas" and "cough gas nightmare" on Google but most of the results are medical-related.

Comment: Don't we typically just delete questions that are, simply, mishearings?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The attorney is not speaking very clearly, but he is saying "a **Kafka-esque** nightmare." The "ka" syllable is almost lost, but you can hear it if you know to listen for it.

> [**Kafkaesque**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kafkaesque), adjective
>
> 1. Marked by a senseless, disorienting, often menacing complexity.
> 2. Marked by surreal distortion and often a sense of impending danger.
> 3. In the manner of something written by Franz Kafka.

The meaning is somewhere between the first and second definitions, or  a combination of both of them.

Comment: This word makes total sense in the context! I have never learned it before.

Comment: @yaobin, here is another word you may find interesting: "cough-gas nightmare" is an example of a [**mondegreen.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen)

Comment: @yaobin, the most well known example of why this is word is used is from Kafka's novella Metamorphosis, where the protagonist wakes up as a giant cockroach and has to deal with his family turning on him because of his repulsive nature. It's a horrifying, surreal nightmare.